# What is the purpose of EnableEventValidation and how does it work?

Tags: asp.net

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFirstColumn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstColumn") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEditMode" runat="server" Text="This is Edit mode"></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn", typeof(int));
    dt.Rows.Add(100);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    if (!IsPostBack)
        GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

If I change `if (!IsPostBack) GridView1.DataBind();` to `GridView1.DataBind();` and try to put GridView into Edit mode by clicking btnEdit, then I get the exception:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using
>   
>   in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

But if I set `EnableEventValidation` to `false`, then `GridView1` won’t enter edit mode ( ie - `GridView1_RowEditing` doesn’t get called ).

BTW – same problem also occurs with other databound controls ( DataList, DetailsView )

> Page. EnableEventValidation gets or
>   sets a value indicating whether the
>   page validates postback and callback
>   events. When the EnableEventValidation
>   property is set to true, ASP.NET
>   validates that a control event
>   originated from the user interface
>   that was rendered by that control. A
>   control registers its events during
>   rendering and then validates the
>   events during postback or callback
>   handling.

a) Why must postback and callback events be evaluated? and how exactly does evaluation happen?

b) Why would calling `GridView1.Databind()` on each postback cause exception when trying to put it into `edit` mode?

c) I also don’t see any reasons why disabling `EnableEventValidation` prevents GridView from entering `edit` mode?! Thus why did

thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a good article about how and why you would want to use EventValidation here:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/21/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument-again.aspx

and MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx

The short answer is event validation is designed to protect the web site from having values injected into the page that can be used to exploit your application in some way.

Comment: Hi, I hope I’m not too late with my reply … anyways … good article, but I still don’t understand why would rebinding GridView on postbacks cause html page to send back to the server ( when trying to put GridView into edit mode ) a value not allowable by Asp.Net?