# Handling the View state values and event validations in ASP.NET Application with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a script for application server by using my machine and now I want to run this script, but when I am running this script, I'm getting following error:

> Validation of view state MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Could anybody can help me? How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract both [__VIEWSTATE](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=viewstate%20asp.net) and [__EVENTVALIDATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909127/what-is-the-purpose-of-enableeventvalidation-and-how-does-it-work) from the previous response, store them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and add as parameters to the next request.

The whole process is known as **correlation** and there is a lot of information on it over the Internet. The most commonly used Test Element for extracting dynamic values from responses is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), however other options exist.

For ASP.NET web applications specifics you can check out [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I did Correlation for both _VIEWSTATE and _EVENTVALIDATION. I supposed to do correlation for those values for two requests. one is successfully passes but another one is getting failed and showing above mentioned message. If my regexp is invalid then both the transactions should get fail, but only one transaction getting fail. So what supposed to i do?