# "Authorization has been denied for this request" in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, asp.net-membership

I am trying to perform load testing using JMeter on my project's web service (search web service for instance), the problem I am facing is that I am getting {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."} in "Response data" tab in JMeter

This same message I also get when I try to paste the same query string (which I am using in JMeter as Path) in browser new tab without logging in first,, but if I login on my project first and then try to paste the query string in browser's new tab then it works fine.

Now the actual problem that I am facing in JMeter is that I am unable to log in to the system using "HTTP Header Manager"
I tried by adding Basic authentication in "HTTP Header Manager" but it didn't worked, then my developer told me that he is using "ASP Membership" authentication instead of Basic authentication,, now I am not sure how to use this type of authentication in JMeter.

I think I have explained my problem in detail here, can any one please help me in this as I am really stuck into it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a cookie-manager to your Thread Group. This will preserve the cookies ( hence sessions) between requests. Next add a http request which will do a POST of your login form then another HTTP Request with your actual request. This way you are imitating the steps you do on your browser - that is - login followed by request.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [ASP.NET Forms Authentication Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) article:

> Forms authentication lets you authenticate users by using your own code and then maintain an authentication token in a cookie or in the page URL.

So depending on implenentation of ASP.NET Forms on server side you can use one of the following test elements:

- [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_URL_Re-writing_Modifier)

Also you may need to perform the correlation of the mandatory dynamic parameters such as [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or [EVENTVALIDATION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909127/what-is-the-purpose-of-enableeventvalidation-and-how-does-it-work). See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide for detailed explanation and walkthrough.